How to rebuild and restart NextJs project remotely with API method?
So i have a NextJs project. In my /admin route, i have a button, where i call some
/same_server/api/update_frontend
This calls a user of a server to go to the folder, where my NextJs project is and works with terminal:

$ssh = new SSH2(config('app-update.ssh-host'), config('app-update.ssh-port'));
if ($ssh->login(config('app-update.ssh-user'), config('app-update.ssh-password'))) {
return $ssh->exec('cd ' . config('app-update.ssh-front-directory') . " && pm2 stop all; pm2 delete all; git restore .; git pull origin main; yarn build; pm2 start yarn --name 'website' -- start");
}

I use pm2 to keep NextJs running. I want to run these commands:
pm2 stop all; pm2 delete all; git restore .; git pull origin main; yarn build; pm2 start yarn --name 'website' -- start

But i failed and figured out, that if i, for example just run yarn dev, it starts nextjs in dev mode, thinks the task is finished, closes terminal and everything stops.
If i run pm2 start yarn --name 'website' -- dev it works fine then.
So how do i correctly initiate all those commands 1 by one, so at the end, ill have completed build and started project kept by pm2?

What helped: connect to a user of a server throught root.
Somehow, you can not run pm2 commands directly from root, need to connect to your user

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
